How to prevent HttpContext User from merging multiple cookie claims
Using .NET6.0, with standard AspNetCore cookie authentication. In our app we currently have 2 cookie authentication schemes; one for regular credentials login, and one for token login (i.e. where a user has been sent a link with an embedded token in order to perform some restricted task).
We noticed, that if a user logs in with a token, and then logs in with credentials, the credentials-cookie is stored next to the token-cookie in their browser, and both are now sent with each request.
What is concerning is that then the HttpContext.User.Claims is now a combination of the claims on both cookies.
This can result in a serious issue where a limited access user on account A, who also happens to be an admin user on account B, can have their claims from both combined to get admin access to account A.
For the time being, we're working around this by signing out all existing authentication schemes before logging a user in with any scheme.
But this seems a little unreliable... if we wanted to introduce a 3rd auth scheme in the future, we'd have to remember to include this in the list of schemes to sign out of during login.
Is there a way out of the box to configure a controller to ignore all but a certain cookie scheme? Or at least see what authentication scheme a particular claim came from?

See this link for help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Actually, there isn't a built-in way in ASP.NET Core to directly configure a controller to ignore all but a specific cookie scheme.
However, standard cookie authentication in ASP.NET Core adds an iss claim (issuer) to the cookie. This can be used to identify which authentication scheme issued the claim. In addition, you can use Custom Claims Principal Factory approach. You could inspect the AuthenticationScheme property within the custom ClaimsPrincipalFactory to determine which scheme issued the claims.
